# How can I automatically update a PowerPivot-File on Sharepoint and protect the raw data from users?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I've got an Excel-Workbook with a PivotTable using PowerPivot. I set up our SharePoint Server to update Pivot-Files every day, which works.
Now I want to update a protected file. Obviously SharePoint can't update the Pivot-Source because its protected.
Is there any way I can update it automatically and still be able to prevent users from messing with the raw data?